# Firebird search with "locate"

Tags: delphi, firebird

I want to do a search with "locate" regardless of uppercase and lowercase (Locate case Insensitive).
like this:

`Form1.Table1.Locate('field', (Edit1.Text),[loCaseInsensitive] ) ;`

With Firebird, I did not know how to do it.

Delphi XE5 + Firebird 2.5 + ZEOSDBO-7.1.4.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 3):

The `Locate` function is a client-side facility which is implemented in most, but not all, TDataSet-descendant components.

It is not a "searching" function, in other words it has no effect on which table rows the dataset retrieves from the server - you still have to do that in whatever way you usually do for the dataset type you are using, e.g. by specifying  SQL statement and then calling `Open` on the dataset.

What `Locate` does is simply (and only) to move the dataset's cursor to the first matching record if there is one, otherwise it returns False.  In other words, if it succeeds, the first record it finds will become the current one for the dataset, i.e. the record which will be displayed by db-aware controls connected to the dataset.

The code you quote should work, *provided* the TDataSet type you are using supports it *and* is already populated with data.  Of course, it will only return True if it manages to locate a matching record.

To find a record matching more than one field value you can do something like

```
Found := Table1.Locate('field1;field2', VarArrayOf([Edit1.Text, Edit2.Text]), [loCaseInsensitive]);
```

Comment: Thank you.                 How please find record with SQL regardless of uppercase and lowercase (Locate case Insensitive).                                this my code:                                                                                                                            `ZQuery1.SQL.Add('SELECT "Field1"  FROM Table where "Field1"='+ QuotedStr(Trim(Edit1.Text)));`                         Firebird 2.5 + ZEOSDBO-7.1.4.

Comment: @Bill: Do not ask a new question in a comment. Instead, post a new question and ask it there using the *Ask Question* button at the top of the page. Your question here was about using Locate, and it has been answered. If you have a different question about SQL, create a new post and ask it there.